# Why are GPIO Expander Registers Being Rewritten?

Tags: i2c, embedded, c++, mbed, expander

I'm using an LPC1768 microcontroller (mbed) and 4 GPIO expanders (MCP23017). I am trying to write to the expanders to enable the pull up resistors and some other functions, but am getting strange behavior when reading from or writing to the registers over I2C.

My code has a read and write function, as well as a busInit() function where I write to a few config registers on the MCP23017s. Main just runs the busInit and then loops printing values of registers of interest on the first MCP23017 (using my read function). I think it must be my write or read functions that are causing this. Relevant snippets:

```
/*
Takes device address, register to read, buffer to store value in.
Reads from a given GPIO expander register for all slaves.
Returns 0 on success, -n on ACK fail, where nth sent byte was NACK by slave.
*/
int readReg(uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *buf) {
    uint8_t opcode = (addr << 1) | 0x40; //format opcode as 0100AAA0, last bit writes
    bus.start();
    if (bus.write(opcode) == 1) { //if control byte ack by slave, send reg byte (2 on timeout, 0 on nack)
        if (bus.write(reg) == 1) { //if register address ack, restart and send next control byte
            bus.start();
            if (bus.write(opcode | 1) == 1) {//send second control byte (opcode with read bit high)
                *buf = bus.read(1); //read reg into buf and send ack
                bus.stop();
                return 0;
            } else {bus.stop(); return -3;}
        } else {bus.stop(); return -2;}
    } else {bus.stop(); return -1;}
}

/*
Takes device address, register to write to, write data buffer.
Writes to a given GPIO expander register for all slaves.
Returns 0 on success, -n on ACK fail, where nth sent byte was NACK by slave.
*/
int writeReg(uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *buf) {
    uint8_t opcode = (addr << 1) | 0x40; //format opcode as 0100AAA0, last bit writes
    bus.start();
    if (bus.write(opcode) == 1) { //if control byte ack by slave, send reg byte (2 on timeout, 0 on nack)
        if (bus.write(reg) == 1) { //if register address ack, send write data
            if (bus.write(*buf) == 1) {
                bus.stop();
                return 0;
            } else {bus.stop(); return -3;}
        } else {bus.stop(); return -2;}
    } else {bus.stop(); return -1;}
}


/*
Init I2C network.
Configures:
-All pins as inputs (except GPA7/GPB7, in datasheet errata they are output only on MCP23017, bidirectional on MCP23S17!)
-Pin logic state to match input
-All pins enabled for interrupt on change (except GPA7/GPB7)
-Interrupt comparison to previous value, not DEFVAL
-Non-banked addressing
-Internally linked interrupt pins
-Automatic pointer incrementation disabled
-INT as active driver output
-Interrupts as active LOW
-100k pull up resistors enabled on all pins (except GPA7/GPB7)
Returns 0 on success, -n on write fail. n = 1 for IOCON, 2 for IODIR, 3 for GPINTEN, 4 for GPPU.
*/
int busInit() {
    bus.frequency(400000);
    uint8_t IOCON_cfg = 0x40;
    uint8_t IODIR_cfg = 0x7F;
    uint8_t GPINTEN_cfg = 0x7F;
    uint8_t GPPU_cfg = 0x7F;

    for (uint8_t addr = 0; addr < 4; addr++) { //write config to each I2C slave
        debug(("Writing config to slave %i\n", addr));
        if (writeReg(addr, 0x0A, &IOCON_cfg)) { //IOCON reg
            debug(("IOCON write failed!\n"));
            return -1;
        } else if (writeReg(addr, 0x00, &IODIR_cfg) ||
                    writeReg(addr, 0x01, &IODIR_cfg)) { //IODIR A/B
            debug(("IODIR write failed!\n"));
            return -2;
        } else if (writeReg(addr, 0x04, &GPINTEN_cfg) ||
                    writeReg(addr, 0x05, &GPINTEN_cfg)) { //GPINTEN A/B
            debug(("GPINTEN write failed!\n"));
            return -3;
        } else if (writeReg(addr, 0x0C, &GPPU_cfg) ||
                    writeReg(addr, 0x0D, &GPPU_cfg)) { //GPPU A/B
            debug(("GPPU write failed!\n"));
            return -4;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output (INCORRECT, NOT the values that I set these to in busInit() and they are changing each time I read them for some reason):

```
========MAIN========
Writing config to slave 0
Writing config to slave 1
Writing config to slave 2
Writing config to slave 3
I2C bus init success!
IOCON=40 | IODIRA=40 | IODIRB=7f | GPINTENA=7f | GPINTENB=7f | INTCONA=7f | INTCONB=7f | GPPUA=7f | GPPUB=7f | GPIOA=7f | GPIOB=0 | INT LOW
IOCON=0 | IODIRA=7f | IODIRB=7f | GPINTENA=7f | GPINTENB=7f | INTCONA=0 | INTCONB=0 | GPPUA=0 | GPPUB=0 | GPIOA=1 | GPIOB=1 | INT LOW
IOCON=7f | IODIRA=7f | IODIRB=7b | GPINTENA=7b | GPINTENB=7b | INTCONA=7b | INTCONB=0 | GPPUA=0 | GPPUB=0 | GPIOA=0 | GPIOB=8 | INT LOW
IOCON=0 | IODIRA=c | IODIRB=c | GPINTENA=4 | GPINTENB=4 | INTCONA=13 | INTCONB=13 | GPPUA=7b | GPPUB=7b | GPIOA=5 | GPIOB=5 | INT LOW
IOCON=0 | IODIRA=0 | IODIRB=0 | GPINTENA=0 | GPINTENB=8 | INTCONA=8 | INTCONB=c | GPPUA=c | GPPUB=c | GPIOA=c | GPIOB=0 | INT LOW
IOCON=0 | IODIRA=7b | IODIRB=7b | GPINTENA=5 | GPINTENB=5 | INTCONA=1 | INTCONB=1 | GPPUA=5 | GPPUB=5 | GPIOA=0 | GPIOB=0 | INT LOW
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    debug(("========MAIN========\n"));
    if (busInit()) {
        debug(("I2C bus init failed!\n"));
    } else {
        debug(("I2C bus init success!\n"));
    }
    while (true) {
        uint8_t rbuf;
        readReg(0x01, 0x0A, &rbuf);
        debug(("IOCON=%x | ", rbuf));
        readReg(0x01, 0x00, &rbuf);
        debug(("IODIRA=%x | ", rbuf));
        readReg(0x01, 0x01, &rbuf);
        debug(("IODIRB=%x | ", rbuf));
        readReg(0x01, 0x04, &rbuf);
        debug(("GPINTENA=%x | ", rbuf));
        readReg(0x01, 0x05, &rbuf);
        debug(("GPINTENB=%x | ", rbuf));
        readReg(0x01, 0x08, &rbuf);
        debug(("INTCONA=%x | ", rbuf));
        readReg(0x01, 0x09, &rbuf);
        debug(("INTCONB=%x | ", rbuf));
        readReg(0x01, 0x0C, &rbuf);
        debug(("GPPUA=%x | ", rbuf));
        readReg(0x01, 0x0D, &rbuf);
        debug(("GPPUB=%x | ", rbuf));
        readReg(0x01, 0x12, &rbuf);
        debug(("GPIOA=%x | ", rbuf));
        readReg(0x01, 0x13, &rbuf);
        debug(("GPIOB=%x | ", rbuf));
        if (INT_0) {
            debug(("INT HIGH\n"));
        } else {
            debug(("INT LOW\n"));
        }
    }
```

[MCP23017 datasheet!](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/MCP23017_Data_Sheet_DS20001952-2998473.pdf)

I have tried:

-Verifying my read/write functions by writing to a register and reading it back.

-Rewiring the physical ICs and disconnecting anything from the GPIO expander inputs. The circuit seems OK and the soldering looks good.

-Waiting a period between reads/writes.

-Examining the I2C lines using a logic analyzer.

-Creating a reproducible example.

-Writing/reading registers in various orders.

-Writing a different config.

Comment: So what does the logic analyzer trace tell you? Can you post a picture of logic analyzer showing read and write  of some register?

Comment: Also, when you are reading from expander, why do you ACK the last byte before stop?

Comment: It would be useful to see the code that produces the output (your main function).

Comment: @Justme Each read and write is properly formatted (according to p13-14 of the datasheet linked in post) and writing a register then reading it back works properly, the problem is that the registers become rewritten somehow afterwards. I'll upload photos ASAP to prove this. The ACK byte is to confirm receipt of the data from the MCP23017 - is this not necessary?

Comment: @DamienD It's been added to the post!

Comment: @Nate.Olson ACK after read means more data expected; you should send NACK after the last read if you don't want to read more.

Comment: @DamienD Thanks for the info, this wasn't clear from my knowledge of I2C and the datasheet. I'll make the change and see if this helps! I have a feeling the readRegister function is actually writing nonsense to various registers after reading so this may be part of it, thanks.

Comment: @DamienD What a foolish issue (as they all are) - that solved it! The ACK after the last byte should have been NACK, when I had thought it was the other way around and looked elsewhere for the issue. Thank you for your time and outside perspective. If you make it an official answer I'll accept/upvote/etc!

Comment: credits go to @Justme for spotting it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending ACK after receiving a byte that is last when reading a register.

It should be a NAK or the expander tries to send first bit of the next byte, and if it is a zero, you can't send stop.

It should be quite visible in the logic analyzer captures.

Which means you have no error checking on e.g. read and stop functions if they fail.